# npm ERR! EPERM : operation not permitted , scandir

Tags: jenkins, npm

Our deployment process uses Jenkins, but sometimes our build fails with the following

[image: error]

We are using **npm version** : 6.7.0. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I;m having a similar issue I think, it would be best if you replace the image with the actual text

Comment: in my case in sveltekit, when I tried to use `<style lang="postcss">` it gives me the bug. turns out that I didn't do `npm i -D postcss`... maybe if anyone else have my same bug, this is the solution

Answer (score 7):

I think the issue is *another process is utilizing that folder* so it's locked down, perhaps from a previous build. I would try the following to resolve your issue:

1. Try running as an admin for your build and see if that resolves the permission error.
2. Clear out your npm cache prior to installing: `npm cache clean --force`
3. Look into [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/) for dependency management.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: In my case, the folder was being used by other terminal process. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For MacBook-

1. Go to **System Preferences**
2. Then, select **Security & Privacy**
3. There next go to top tapbar- in **Privacy**
4. At left, you will see **Full Disk Access**
5. For Full Disk Access, there will be list here have to select **Terminal**, if not selected
6. If there is no Terminal option .
   Then add it by clicking **+ plus** and you will go to finder
7. Select **application** at left side
8. Then, go to **Utilities**
   9.inside utilities, you will **Terminal**, select it and click on open button

That set

Now, you will **not** get error- ***npm ERR! EPERM : operation not permitted , scandir***

Answer (score 3):

This is 2022 and I still stumbled on this issue. If you had similar issue, here is how I fixed it. (Remember to launch cmd as admin).

1. Stop your running server (ctr + C)
2. npm cache clean --force

Problem Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for us:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Answer (score 0):

I have installed nodejs plugin . I have added nodejs installer with version NodeJS 8.15.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBFCh.png)

I configured the job such that it uses this
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYJiV.png)
that fixed the issue