# How to get all apps that is installed from microsoft store in windows with nodejs？

Tags: node.js, windows

If i scan `C:/Program Files/WindowsApps/` ,it will return permission error.

How could i get the list of windows apps from microsoft store?

The error is
`operation not permitted, scandir 'C:/Program Files/WindowsApps'`

```js
//I use glob to scan all the exe in the windowsApps dictionary
const glob = require("glob");
const exes = []
const filePattern = path.resolve(startMenu, "**/*.exe").replace(/\\/g, "/");
  // console.log(filePattern);
exes.push(glob.sync(filePattern));
```

Comment: Submit some code

Comment: If you are trying to get all folder names from `C:/Program Files/WindowsApps`, that's easy - use `fs.readdir(...)`

Comment: @DVN-Anakin but it seems that I couldn't visit the dictionary, pleace tell me that in which way could I get the windows app.

Comment: Try running as an admin for your build and see if that resolves the permission error.

Answer (score 1):

To simply get names of directories within `C:/Program Files/WindowsApps` you could do:

```
const folder = 'C:/Program Files/WindowsApps';
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir(folder, (err, files) => {
  files.forEach((file, index) => {
    console.log((index + 1) + ') ' + file);
  });
});
```

The result would look like this:

```
1) AppleInc.iCloud_13.0.201.0_x86_...
2) Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge.Stable_89.0.774.68...
3) Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.2_2.2.29512.0_x64__...
...
```

Comment: I  run this script and it return error: `[Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps'] {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps'
}`

Comment: Apparently clearing the NPM cache should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54639841/npm-err-eperm-operation-not-permitted-scandir

Comment: Try running as an admin for your build and see if that resolves the permission error.